# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm able to access other websites like Youtube, account.google.com etc except [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). When I try to access [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in the chromium browser, it returns `www.google.com unexpectedly closed the connection.` and `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`.

Then I tried with curl.

```
$ curl -x http://127.0.0.1:1080 -v https://www.google.com
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 1080 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.google.com:443
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.75.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443
```

I can't find a similar problem on the internet and now I'm at complete loss. Why does this happen, and how to fix it?

(I'm not quite familiar with stuffs like SSL, so I'm sorry that I may not able to give enough information. Thanks for answering the question)

EDIT: For comparison:

```
$ curl -x http://127.0.0.1:1080 -v https://www.youtube.com
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 1080 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.youtube.com:443
> CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.youtube.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.75.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Jan 19 07:57:09 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 13 07:57:08 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.youtube.com" matched cert's "*.youtube.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x56071ebe5910)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.youtube.com
> user-agent: curl/7.75.0
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
...(Normal site data)
```

Comment: Have you tried this in a different environment. Have you tried it without proxy?

Comment: I use proxy to bypass restrictions, so I cannot test without proxy. And what do you mean by "a different environment"?

Comment: Different network used by the proxy in this case. My guess is that the problem is caused by the proxy itself or the network it is connected too (i.e. there is some filtering). Nothing known though, neither about the network nor about the proxy.

Comment: I tend to think this is a issue related to openssl because:
(1) My phone using basically the same proxy could access www.google.com, meaning the proxy and the network itself should be working;
(2) Error message `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443`

Comment: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL is a problem with the underlying TCP connection, not a SSL issue. Looks like the connection was closed before the server response in the TLS handshake was received. And using **basically** the same proxy is not **actually** using the same proxy :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have any idea on what problem it **could** be?

Comment: Hard to tell, maybe something intercepting the connections on the way. But like I said, I have no idea of the kind of proxy or environment you are in so it is hard to even make educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for the last two weeks, and whatever I did could not fix the problem. But I found out the problem was with my certificate file.

The receiving host needed a cert file for authentication and I used my p12 file to extract the cert and the key, and my guess is that the extraction my have caused the cert and the key to become corrupted.

So instead of using the extracted files, I used the original p12 file and modified my code as follows.

curl -k --cert-type P12 --cert browser.p12: https://localhost:8443/solr

Answer (score 0):

you should look up "https://github.com/ShadowsocksR-Live/shadowsocksr-native#sample-configure-file", the config.json demo maybe help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.